# Error in android gradle plugin : it must have dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for firebase service to work as intended

Tags: android

The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error clearly says that you're missing the Firebase Core library in your `app/build.gradle`.

Follow the steps below on [how to set up Firebase in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). Don't forget to add

```
dependencies {
 // ...
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'

 // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure that you've added
 // Google's Maven repository to your root-level build.gradle file
}
```

In your app/build.gradle file if you've already followed all the steps correctly.